# Pushing entire Rundeck configuration to github

Tags: github, rundeck

I want to push entire Rundeck configuration to Github. Is there any way for doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [Rundeck configuration layout](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/configuration-file-reference.html), all you would need to do is:

```
cd $RDECK_BASE
git init .
git remote add origin /url/new/empty/GitHub/repo

echo '*'>.gitignore
echo '!/etc/'>.gitignore
echo '!/server/'>.gitignore
echo '/server/*'>.gitignore
echo '!/server/config/'>.gitignore

git add .
git commit -m "Rundeck config"
git push -u master
```

Basically, you need to ignore what is *not* configuration before adding everything else (ie, the config files), and pushing to your own GitHub repo.

Make sure those files don't have sensitive credential information in them though (or at least push them to a *private* GitHub repo if you have one)